# Failed to synchronize segments. Message: typeKey should not be null

Tags: experience-analytics

when trying to connect to XConnect and do any operation like "Deploy Market Definitions" from control panel. This particular error above happens when Sitecore is starting up. I have no idea where to look for or what could be causing this error, can anyone give me a tip?

```
7812 05:41:26 FATAL [Experience Analytics]: Failed to synchronize segments. Message: typeKey should not be null.
Parameter name: typeKey. Details:    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.GetByTypeAsync(DefinitionTypeKey typeKey)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.GetAll(NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsManager.GetSegmentsToSynchronize()
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsManager.SynchronizeAllSegments()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsProcessor.<Process>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logs of the processing server I saw that the SQL user didn't have rights to run stored procedures and that was causing it to fail when getting some data from the DB, this is why I was getting null references.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Do you find any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `cm` and `prc` logs is a good way to start digging in.

In my case, because I was using self signed certificates, I first had to work through certificate errors due to invalid certificates not being allowed. This [Sitecore page](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/replace-a-sitecore-client-certificate-in-azure.html) is a good guide. If you continue to get those errors, you missed a setting update somewhere. Check the main Web.config as well.

Once I worked through those errors, I saw this error in `prc`:

```
ERROR [Path Analyzer] Error during aggregation.
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Login failed for user 'masteruser'.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

This corroborates what @anderson-fortaleza found -- SQL connection / permission issues.

Other things to check:

- Do all of your Solr cores/collections exist? Do they all show up in the Indexing manager window?
- Did you deploy marketing definitions?
- Did you restart all of your app services / VMs?